# Piecewise of different functions

Tags: differential-equations

You know, NDsolve coupled with Piecewise can be used to solve a series of discontinuous differential equations. But what if one of the function is different? For example:

$$z''(t)=\begin{cases}x(t)-(1+y(t)), & \text{if } x>(1+y) \\
\\
\\
x(t)+(1+y(t)), & \text{if } x<-(1+y)
\end{cases}
$$
$$\rm{and}$$
$$z'(t)=0, \rm{if }  |x|<(1+y)
$$
I tried something like below

```
xyz = First@NDSolve[{x''[t] == -2.25 Cos[1.5 t] - x[t] - x'[t], 
x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0, 
y''[t] == -1.125 Cos[1.5 t] - 4 y[t] - y'[t], 
y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0, 
z''[t] == Piecewise[{
    {x[t] - (1 + y[t]), x[t] > 1 + y[t]}, 
    {0, Abs[x[t]] <= 1 + y[t]}, 
    {x[t] + (1 + y[t]), x[t] < -1 - y[t]}}], 
z[0] == 0}, 
{x, y, z}, {t, 0, 30}];
```

but have no idea how to correctly incorporate $z'(t)$ condition.

Comment: Please write down the code you've tried

Comment: @belisarius What `f` are you talking about?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I need a new pair of lenses

Answer (score 1):

Without making any claims about whether the problem is well posed, it appears possible to make Mathematica compute a solution. Maybe I've taken too many liberties with the problem, but consider the following.
$$
z'(t) = \begin{cases}
  0, & \text{if}~|x|<(1+y) \\
  q(t), & \text{if}~|x|>(1+y)
\end{cases}
$$
$$
q'(t)=\begin{cases}
  x(t)-(1+y(t)), & \text{if}~x>(1+y) \\
  x(t)+(1+y(t)), & \text{if}~x<-(1+y) \\
  0, & \text{if}~|x|<(1+y)
\end{cases}
$$

The code below gives a result for $z(t)$ that looks like a staircase. Is that what you expect?

```
T = 30;
xySol = First@NDSolve[{
  x''[t] == -2.25 Cos[1.5 t] - x[t] - x'[t], x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0,
  y''[t] == -1.125 Cos[1.5 t] - 4 y[t] - y'[t], y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0}, {x, y}, {t, 0, T}];

zSol = First@NDSolve[{
  q'[t] == Piecewise[{
    {x[t] - (1 + y[t]), x[t] > (1 + y[t])},
    {x[t] + (1 + y[t]), x[t] < -(1 + y[t])}} /. xySol, 0],
  z'[t] == Piecewise[{
    {0, Abs[x[t]] < (1 + y[t])}} /. xySol,
    q[t]],
  q[0] == 0,z[0] == 0}, {q, z}, {t, 0, T}]
```